# Android-How to close an open port in android?

Tags: java, android, port, kill

I have an app (A),from Google play, that has a server (Activity), I know the port number that used by this server. How to close that port from my app (B)!. Closing that port will close the server and that is my end target!

Edit: I tried to kill the app using the follwoing, but the server still running, so I was thinking to close the port which cause to close the server!

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you gave it minus, I think you should explain your point of view!!!!

Comment: Why don't you just close the server/app? It will close the port also i think.

Comment: When I try to close the app using killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName), the server continue running, that is why I am asking to close the port instead!

Comment: Which app are you talking about?

Comment: The app name is IP Webcam.

Comment: I wonder which scenaro runs that apparently you do not want to remove the app from your device to solve the problem. It looks that some times you want to use it and some times want to get rid of it. Is IP Camera (and its server) automatically started at boot?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName);
```

I don't this can be done without either uid sharing between the processes or rooting your device.

Both applications will require identical android:sharedUserId="some_string" manifest entries for shared uid workability.

Otherwise you are sandboxed ;)